Let $X$ be a complex normed vector space, and let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|(n + \lambda)x + y\| - \|nx + y\|$.
This is from Torchinsky's problem book in functional analysis (Problem 8.4). The problem statement is as follows:

Let $X$ be a real or complex normed linear space, $x, y \in X$, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Find $\lim _n(\|(n+\lambda) x+y\|-\|n x+y\|)$.

The solution (with no proof) that the book gives is $\|\lambda x\|$.
The only progress I can seem to make is that the triangle inequality would yield you an upper-bound of $\|\lambda x\|$, but I cannot get a suitable lower-bound (say, to utilize the squeeze theorem).

Expand with $|(n+\lambda)x+y| + |nx+y|$.

The correct answer is $\lambda \|x\|$, rather than $\|\lambda x\|$. Below I give estimations from both sides. Also we assume $n$ large enough, so $n + \lambda > 0$.
The triangle inequality implies:
$$
\|(n + \lambda)x + (1 + \frac{\lambda}{n})y\| + \|\frac{\lambda}{n} y\| \ge \|(n + \lambda)x + y \| \ge \|(n + \lambda)x + (1 + \frac{\lambda}{n})y\| - \|\frac{\lambda}{n}y\|
$$
$$\frac{n + \lambda}{n} \| nx + y\| + \frac{|\lambda|}{n}\|y\| \ge \|(n + \lambda)x + y \| \ge \frac{n+\lambda}{n} \|nx + y\| - \frac{|\lambda|}{n}\|y\|$$
$$
\frac{\lambda}{n} \| nx + y\| + \frac{|\lambda|}{n}\|y\| \ge \|(n + \lambda)x + y \| - \|nx + y\| \ge \frac{\lambda}{n} \| nx + y\| - \frac{|\lambda|}{n}\|y\|$$
Both estimates converge to $\lambda \|x\|$.

First we have $$\|(n+\lambda)x+y\|^2 = \langle (n+\lambda)x+y,(n+\lambda)x+y\rangle \\= \langle(n+\lambda)x ,(n+\lambda)x+y\rangle +\langle y,(n+\lambda)x+y\rangle \\= \langle(n+\lambda)x,(n+\lambda)x\rangle +\langle (n+\lambda)x,y\rangle + \langle y, (n+\lambda)x\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle \\ = (n+\lambda)^2\langle x,x \rangle + (n+\lambda)\langle x,y\rangle + (n+\lambda)\langle y,x\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle$$
and then we have $$\|nx+y\|^2 = \langle nx+y,nx+y\rangle = \langle nx,nx+y \rangle +\langle y,nx+y\rangle \\ =\langle nx,nx\rangle + \langle nx,y\rangle + \langle y,nx\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle \\ = n^2\langle x,x\rangle + n \langle x,y\rangle + n \langle y,x\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle$$
Now taking square roots and subtracting gives $$\|(n+\lambda) x + y \|-\|xn+y\|=\lambda \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle} +(\sqrt{n+\lambda}-\sqrt{n})\sqrt{\langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,x \rangle})$$
and finally since $\lambda  \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle} = \lambda \|x||$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{\lambda + n}-\sqrt{n} =0$ we are done.

OP doesn’t seem to be assuming the norm comes from an inner product.
